# Is there any attempt to explain irrational numbers from a geometrical point of view?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

I'm trying to understand irrational numbers as the result of comparing different referential symmetries, and I'd like to know if there have been any attempt to explain irrationality from any geometrical point of view.

Comment: As far as I know, the first number to be known not to be rational is the Golden ratio which is something quite geometrical. And the proof of irrationality is that, if it were a fraction, then $m/n=n/(m-n)$ so you could be reducing the fraction forever. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Irrationality

Comment: Many thanks Peter, that's useful to me, I'm going to think about the golden ratio

Comment: https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/9780262661829_sch_0001.pdf

Comment: May thanks Fred, I'm going to read it

Comment: Hey @FredKline I've found something of my interest in the MIT paper you linked. Thanks again. It uses the term "mongrel ratio" when it comes to describing irrationality in musical terms (page 20). I also liked very much the musical approach. Google only finds 10 results for that expression, and the only one related to maths is that MIT paper/book. I'm interested in it because I guess irrationality appears because of a mixture of different referential symmetries. Maybe looking for other similar expressions I could find more information. Also I'll try to understand better the musical perspective

Answer (score 2):

Considering the pythagorean theorem on isosleces triangles:

Sidelength of a,b = 1 -> $ c = \sqrt2 $ 
Sidelength of a,b = 2 -> $ c = \sqrt8 $ 
... 
$ c = \sqrt{(2*a^2)} = \sqrt2*a $

However no matter how big you choose a and b to be *as long as they are both rational*, you never get a result which is not irrational.
One would assume though if you construct it on paper, and $\sqrt2$ was a rational number, then you could find a solution which has an integer distance as side c.
But this is never the case.

*after seeing Rahuls comment (ofc choices like a = $\sqrt2$ break this)*

Comment: "no matter how big you choose a and b to be, you never get a result which is not irrational"... as long as $a$ and $b$ are both rational.

Comment: Thank you. That's a description about irrationality, but what I'd like to know  is if there have been any attempt to explain geometrically why it happens. I  think we are comparing squares that have a different center of symmetry.

Comment: You mean why for this example c is not rational? For me this is somehow the same, as you can not find a rational c.

Comment: Yep... I'm trying to think about why we cannot find a rational c...

Comment: @user6562 i just noticed that wikipedia uses the same idea - [Irrational Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number)

Comment: Thank you for your help, Wikipedia is awesome, although I was thinking in another thing.